# Calling LinkedIn guided profile setup parts directly

Tags: linkedin, profile

I want to call a specific part of the profile guided setup from my web app, so that users can fill their profile at the correct part.

I know this one works;

> http://www.linkedin.com/profile/guided?startTask=CERTIFICATION_NAME&force=true

It will launch the guided profile setup in the Certifications part.

Any ideas for others (startTask value), for example to launch adding a new Course?